# Rsync archive not copying permissions

Tags: rsync, nas, synology

I'm running this command to synchronize files on my NAS and internal hard drive (MBP 2018 Big Sur) zsh.

I'm running `rsync -avi --delete /Volumes/DRIVENAME/ /Volumes/NAS/folder/DRIVENAME/` where /Volumes/DRIVENAME/ is an internal APFS drive created with Disk Utility.

Output: one line for each of the files

```
.d...p... path/to/filename.txt
```

The command keeps syncing the same files, I tried running this a while back and it was working fine, i.e. files would not be copied again.  I think zsh might have something to do with this.

Please let me know what flags I may be able to try or let me know what's causing this to happen.

Thanks

Comment: zsh has nothing to do with this. Zsh is the shell you run, nothing to do with ohow you sotore your data

Comment: Are you sure your NAS is using a filesystem that knows how to handle permissions?  Many NAS systems are designed for windoze and may not comprehend permissions as Linux and other unix-like systems handle them.  For example, doing an rsync to a fat32 target will probably "accept" the user, group, and permissions while silently dropping them.  Additional details like this really help in figuring out your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Different filesystems can have different sets of permissions and that means that you cannot always preserve them when copying/moving.

Even the same filesystem could be mounted with options that would make it impossible to preserve permissions.

In this case you probably want to add the `--no-perms` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear to me. You seem to be having an issue with `rsync`, but it's not quite clear what it is - except that it's not doing what you *expected* it to do. I'm not sure how to answer except to cover some basics:

**1. Your Q contained this:**

> Output: one line for each of the files

```
.d...p... path/to/filename.txt
```

This appears to be one line from your output that is due to the `-i` option. Here's a [resource to help you understand how to interpret](http://www.staroceans.org/e-book/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html) each of these lines. If you consult this resource (or read `man rsync`) you'll understand this line from your question means that the *directory* (`d`) listed has a different set of *permissions* (`p`) on the *destination* than it does for the *source*

**2. The `-a` option you used is meaningful to the outcome of your `rsync` command:**

`-a` = `-rlptgoD`

`p` means `preserve permissions`; i.e. the same permissions to which your one line output refers. ***If it can***, `rsync` will change the permissions on the destination to match the permissions on the source. ***rsync does not transfer a file to accomplish this*** - it merely changes the permissions. You provided no error messages in your question, so we have to assume that `rsync` accomplished this permission change without further ado. If that's not the case, please edit your question.

If `rsync` is unable to change permissions on the destination, you can find more options that will help you overcome this problem. Review `man rsync`, paying particular attention to the `--fake-super` (and related) options. This option can be very useful in dealing with (for example) filesystems on NAS devices - which are typically quite different from `APFS`.

**3. [FWIW](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+what+it%27s+worth):**

The APFS in current use on MacOS is a proprietary pos. Apple is very fond of doing things differently, and make extensive use of *metadata* in their filesystem. This metadata plays a significant role in various MacOS functions, which means that to preserve that functionality, you must preserve the metadata! Here in particular, `rsync` has options that support this objective. The *metadata* that Apple depends on so heavily is encoded in *extended attributes* (`xattr`, or the `-X` option in rsync) and *access contol lists* (`--acls`, or the `-A` option in rsync).

I use a NAS to synchronize some of my user data between Mac systems. My most frequently used `rsync` commands are these:

- From MacOS-to-NAS:

```bash
$ rsync -rlAXtgoDvi --fake-super /mac/source/folders/ /nas/dest/folders
```

- From NAS-to-MacOS

```bash
$ rsync -rlAXtgoDvi --fake-super /nas/source/folders/ /mac/dest/folders
```

This is quite useful: even though my NAS uses a completely different file system than the Macs, `rsync` is able to preserve all of the Mac's metadata on the NAS, and then restore it upon arrival at its APFS destination.